# Sending emails with SendGrid on Azure using C# async, await

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, sendgrid

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/) to send emails from my Azure web role using SendGrid.

This is the relevant part from the tutorial:

```
// Create credentials, specifying your user name and password.
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

// Create an REST transport for sending email.
var transportREST = REST.GetInstance(credentials);

// Send the email.
transportREST.Deliver(myMessage);
```

It seems to me that the `transportREST.Deliver` function is synchronous. Since it's performing IO I'd prefer to use the new .NET 4.5 **async, await** instead (all my other code is completely asynchronous). Is this possible? Is there an async API for SendGrid or some way to wrap the existing call?

Comment: “or some way to wrap the existing call” You can't wrap synchronous method to make it asynchronous.

Comment: @svick I know, but if I spawn a new thread for the blocking bit and async on it, this might be a little better and free my server thread-pool to handle other clients asynchronously.. is this better than blocking? or maybe have some worker thread work on sending these blocking emails and add to its queue..

Comment: No, actually that won't help. Threads are relatively heavy-weight and creating a thread just for this one operation is likely going to make your performance worse. It's not better thank blocking, because it *is* blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the SendGrid C# library doesn't haven't async methods because we wanted to maintain compatibility with .NET 4.0.

You could easily make this change yourself. In fact, [here's a commit](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/commit/7d436f6cb48b1fe8f12949fea77bb7ea87fe3cc3) that I later reverted after we decided to stick with .NET 4.0.

**Update:** As of Oct 24 2013 and sendgrid-csharp 1.2.1, there is a DeliverAsync method available

Comment: Might be a good idea to support both versions (possibly in the same source with some conditional attribute magic). All cloud api is making this transition (Azure Storage new RC is async already)

Comment: another small request: please use the xxxAsync naming convention in the async versions

Comment: Couple of comments on the commit you linked to: 1. your `async` methods return void (they should return `Task`), so they wouldn't be that useful (you couldn't `await` them).  2. you could maintain compatability with .NET 4.0 by having these methods return `Task`s and in the method use `.ContinueWith` rather than `await` (in the commit, it doesn't look like it would be very difficult to use `.ContinueWith` vs `await`.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I will do some research and consider the options. Feel free to post issues on the github repo as well. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Comment: I've added an issue on the [github repo ](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/34) and will start  in on this next week.

Comment: FYI I extended a fork of this to handle async (.NET40), please take a look: https://github.com/HakanL/sendgridplus-csharp

Comment: DeliverAsync method is now available.

Comment: Are the REST or SMTP SendGrid transport instances thread safe?

Comment: @bwest DeliverAsync is not available on ITransport interface, which is dissapointing -(

Comment: @trailmax it is, actually. At least in Sendgrid 4.0.0.